# String with line breaks fails to textarea.val()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I got my Laravel project, where the CRUD in few places based on bootstrap modal. However, my record edit procedure is working not like I expected...

*My problem:*
I got table with records and its every row has edit button. When I press it my modal window inputs should be filled and it does right, **if only textarea field does not contain line break**. If it does, my data push **breaks**.

Console error:
[Chrome console drops error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0F4L.png)

This is how I pass data to jQuery:

```
@foreach($dukList as $duk)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$duk->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$duk->duk_title}}</td>
        <td>{{$duk->duk_content}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editduk" onclick="setDukEditData('{{$duk->id}}','{{$duk->duk_title}}','{{$duk->duk_content}}')"><span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is how I try to populate edit modal with data:

```
function setDukEditData(id, duk_title, duk_content) {
    $("#duk_title_edit").val(duk_title);
    $("#duk_content_edit").val(duk_content);
    $("#dukEdit").attr("action", "{{URL::to('/update-duk')}}/" + id);
}
```

This is a part of my modal window of record edit:

```
<!-- form starts -->
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="duk_title">Question</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="duk_title_edit" name="duk_title_edit" minlength="10" maxlength="100" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="duk_content">Content</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="duk_content_edit" name="duk_content_edit" style="resize: none;" maxlength="500" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like you need to be escaping the line break when used as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 $( "#duk_content_edit" ).html( $( "#duk_content" ).val().replace('\n', '<br/>') );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution. My code, which I provided in this topic fails then I try pass data(with line break) to jQuery function onclick="setDukEditData(...)"